# Problem getting apache to default to a particular JKMount using mod_jk

Tags: apache, tomcat, web-applications, mod-jk

I have an apache instance fronting 4 tomcat webapps, lets call them app1, app2, app3, app4. I'm using mod_jk to act as the connector and I've set up apache with JKMount entries for each and I can happily hit:

server:8080/app1

server:8080/app2

server:8080/app3

server:8080/app4

But what i actually want is to have all the traffic for app1, app2 and app3 be addressed as above, but with app4 (only) addressed on:

server:8080/

I was sure this was going to be easy, but i can't figure it out. Any ideas?

Gordon

Answer (score 4):

If I understand correctly, you want to set app4 as the default web app - so that it will be available directly as server:8080/

all you need to do is you can set the path as `""` in a `Context` element within `<Host>` in `server.xml` on Tomcat.
. This should work

```
<Context docBase="/var/lib/tomcat6/webapps/app4/" path="" reloadable="true>
```

From the Tomcat docs,

> If you specify a context path of an
>   empty string (""), you are defining
>   the default web application for this
>   Host, which will process all requests
>   not assigned to other Contexts

Ensure you restart Apache and Tomcat once to enable the changes.

Note: From the Tomcat 6 docs http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-6.0-doc/config/context.html#Introduction it is recommended not to put this in server.xml since you need to restart Tomcat for any changes.

> The default web application may be
>   defined by using a file called
>   ROOT.xml

but i have not tried that option myself.

Answer (score 1):

As of Tomcat 5.5 (I don't know about earlier versions) you can rename app4 to **ROOT.war** if it's a WAR file or **ROOT/** if it's a directory.  Logically you will have to overwrite any existing ROOT.war or ROOT/ if there is one present.